# Will copy/pasting files from a CD work to install a program?

Tags: installation

I am asking this because my disks are getting old (I legally purchased the software) and that most modern PCs don't even come with disk drives anymore but just USBs at the front end. I doubt my disks are going to last another year given the amount of scratches and beating on them already. The CD/DVD era is way long gone, however I do need to install programs back then that were stored in disks.

My question is (Because I've never tried it before oddly), can I copy and paste all the files from a disk to my computer and then install the program from there? Is this how its done or are there more efficient ways?

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not work depending on the program (although I postulate it will work for most programs).

Assuming the disk is still readable, and assuming disk space is not an issue, a better way of preserving your data would be to create an ISO (ie disk file) of the CD/DVD.  You can then use appropriate software to mount ISO as a virtual DVD and even burn copies to disk later on.

I expect this will work for the vast majority of software, although I am fairly certain there is some software - normally games - out there which relies on [deliberate corruptions of DVDs/CD's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_and_DVD_copy_protection) for copy protection to work.   If you are unlucky enough to have these (and its unlikely) your best bet is finding a cracked version online, although you may be able to find software to make ISOs out of these corrupt disks as well.

Comment: Thanks. All this time i've been handling with ISOs and I mostly open them but never tried making an ISO file from a cd/dvd. I am going to try it out with my legally purchased disks that are over 15 years old now!